# Automatically fixing chktex "Use \( ... \) instead of $ ... $"

Tags: warnings, chktex

I have a few documents that result in a lot of warnings because I've been using `$...$` instead of `\(...\)` and a few other tiny details.

How can I automatically fix these chktex warnings? vscode provides a "quick fix" but I would need to manually apply in each case.

**Update:**

I was wondering if there is some command line tool (or similar) that can automatically fix these warnings. `vscode` can fix warnings one by one automatically, but that is too time consuming.

**Update2:**

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\begin{document}
$1+1=2$
\end{document}
```

Here is the minimum command line that vscode executes:

```
chktex -wall example.tex
```

and the output:

```
ChkTeX v1.7.6 - Copyright 1995-96 Jens T. Berger Thielemann. 
Compiled with POSIX extended regex support. 
Warning 46 in example.tex line 3: Use \( ... \) instead of $ ... $.
$1+1=2$
^^^^^^^                       
No errors printed; One warning printed; No user suppressed warnings; No line suppressed warnings. 
See the manual for how to suppress some or all of these warnings/errors.
```

Comment: Please provide a minimum working example of a LaTeX document that the `$`-related warning messages. For sure, on MacTeX2018, passing `\documentclass{article} \begin{document} $1+1=2$ \end{document}` thru `chktex` does *not* generate any `$`-related warning messages.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with using `$` but if you want to change to `\(` any text editor should allow you to replace `$...$` by `\(...\)` using regular expression search.replace

Comment: There's also [debuck](https://github.com/loopspace/debuck) by [Loop Space](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/86/loop-space), which performs this replacement.

Comment: Just FYI, I don't recommend running with `-wall`, there are some weird warnings that almost no-one would actually want, such as warning about comments.  This warning (about $) is off by default because it's not as important as others.  That said, ChkTeX doesn't provide automatic fixing.

Answer (score 7):

You can accomplish this in `vscode` by doing a find-replace with a regex:

Press `Ctrl + Shift + h` (or use the menu bar `Edit > Replace in Files`)
In the search field enter this regex:
`\$([^$]+)\$`
Make sure the "Use Regular Expression" button is checked (`Alt + r`)
In the replace field enter:
`\($1\)`
files to include:
`*.tex`

Click the "Replace All" button (`Ctrl + Alt + Enter`)
and watch the magic happen

Comment: Just as a note, for those that are using `$$a$$` instead of `\[a\]`, you should replace `\$\$([^$]+)\$\$` with `\[$1\]` first.

Answer (score 7):

This message is number 46 warning of ChkTex，just append `-n46` to construct the compile command, which means ignoring the number 46 warning. As illustrated below(It's an option in VSCode extensions setting).[image: VSCode Extensions Setting]More detail in the document of ChkTex [ChkTex.dvi](https://www.nongnu.org/chktex/ChkTeX.pdf)